# Ubuntu store always not loading in ubuntu 20.04, why is that?

Tags: dual-boot, vpn, 20.04, proxy, ubuntu-store

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in 'Dual boot mode' alongside W10.

Internet connectivity is working as usual/expected within browser and terminal while browsing as well as downloading or upgrading packages, with exception to 'Ubuntu Software' store from the day of installation it is not working as expected!

**Update:**
I am using a VPN connection in my machine, does it have any relation with this?

Any comments/suggestions please?

It always shows a loading scree(black screen with 3 dots) i guess,

[image: Loading screen of Ubuntu Software store]

After many hours also, it shows the same. If I tried to search for any particular app, at times only it shows the result most of the time it shows only the spinner icon

[image: Searching for a particular software in store]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the VPN connection I was testing that time.

As soon I stopped using it, no more issues with 'Software Center'.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes up with snap-store and it is stucks every time

You can install Gnome-software and it will fix the ubuntu software issue

```
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

To remove the default Ubuntu Software

Goto *Gnome-software>>Installed(tab)>>Remove Snap-store*

Comment: Yeah, with this i reinstalled the genome software, thanks :)
But still, as it didn't fix the snap store issue, i couldn't mark this 'as the solution'

Comment: Are you using Mobile Hotspot?

Comment: Yes, i am using mobile Hot-spot only

Comment: Then Disable IPv6 In your PC
`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`
`sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`
This command will temporarly disable IPv6 in your PC

Comment: I would like to try that, but before would like to know more on why specifically disabling the IPV6, And how it impacts the snap-store ?
In addition to store, how it affects the other apps/browsers while using internet?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. As a workaround, enter the System Monitor, find the gnome-software entry and end the process. Then open the store again.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same issue, try reinstall the `snap-store`

```
snap remove snap-store && snap install snap-store
```

Then re-open the snap-store, the icon may change to a different one.